# How to let gcc print ALL libraries linked?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Even for the simplest "hello world" program, which can be compiled and linked using command

```
"gcc -o hello hello.c"
```

, there must be some version of standard C library linked to build target from hello.o. What I was looking for was exactly that kind of libraries that were "secretly" linked by gcc in a compile-link process.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I don't know gcc but UNIX ldd program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ gcc -o hello -Xlinker -v hello.c 
collect2 version 4.6.3 (x86-64 Linux/ELF)
/usr/bin/ld --sysroot=/ --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o hello /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../.. -v /tmp/ccvjXRF7.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22
```

`-Xlinker --verbose` will give even more info, including exactly which libraries are resolved and included. An excerpt:

```
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so succeeded
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so)
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

To list just the dynamically linked libaries, run `ldd` on the resulting binary.

```
$ ldd hello
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff68dad000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fac49f46000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fac4a323000)
```

Answer (score 3):

`-Wl,-Map,mapfile.txt` will let ld produce a load map file containing all libraries linked as well as a cross reference list of symbols

Comment: It seems you need `--Wl,--cref` to get the cross-reference table, which includes all symbols and the library containing them (without this, it seems the linker map only lists one symbol for each library, maybe the one that caused this library to be included?).

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass `-v` to GCC which tells it to print out all the options it uses for compilation and how the linker is invoked, or you can tell GCC to pass `-v` just to the linker, with `-Wl,-v` and that will print just the linker command, including all the libraries being linked to.